# The polynomial $x^p - 2px+p$

Tags: galois-theory

Good evening to everyone! I am trying for more than 2 hours to solve the next exercise, which I found in some lecture notes in Galois theory. The exercise has 3 parts and I managed to solve only parts i) and ii). So here we go :

Let $p$ be a prime number.

i)Show that if a subgroup $ H \leq S_p$ contains a cycle of length $p$ and a cycle of length $2$ then $H\equiv S_p$. ( I already proved this)

ii)If an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ has degree $p\geq 5$ and exactly two non-real roots (e.g. $\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ ) , then it is not solvable in radicals. (also proved)

iii)The polynomial $x^p-2px+p$ has a Galois group isomorphic to $S_p$, so it is not solvable in radicals.($p\geq 5$)

Well, the third part is the one I cannot solve. The chapter in which I found this exercise treats the radical extensions and the connection between the Galois group of a polynomial and its solvability. I have proved that the above polynomial is irreducible (Eisenstein's criterion), has exactly 3 roots in $\mathbb{R}$ (using calculus and the derivative)so it has $p-3$ roots  $\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, which of course are conjugate. I also proved that $\mathrm{Gal}(K,\mathbb{Q})$ contains a cycle of length $p$ (because, if $K$ is the splitting field of $f$ , then $|\mathrm{Gal}(K,\mathbb{Q})|=[K:\mathbb{Q}(a)][\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]=\lambda p)$. But I cannot prove that it contains a cycle of length $2$ which would lead to the result, because of part i). I thought that if we could prove that it contains $A_p$ (the even permutations), then we are ok, but how can we do that?

Does anyone have any idea?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Use that the Galois group contains a $p$-cycle (under the embedding into $S_p$, and that complex conjugation corresponds to $2$-cycles. Then use that $S_p$ can be generated by a $2$-cycle and a $p$-cycle.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, it contains a $p$-cycle but I can not show that it contains a $2$-cycle, and this is because the conjugate isomorphism is a composition of disjoint $2$- cycles and not a single cycle itself. For example if the polynomial is of degree $p=7$ and $z_1, \bar{z_1}, z_2, \bar {z_2}$ are the complex roots, then the conjugate isomorphism can be represented as  $\sigma=(1 2)\circ(3 4)$,which is not a cycle, but a composition of $2$-cycles.